How to implement optional sign in using Authenticator component?
Currently, we use the Authenticator by wrapping it around our app. This assumes that every user needs to be logged in either as guest or a regular account.
Is it possible for the authentication to be optional? I have a page that will display standard public info. Logging in will display additional user specific info but is otherwise optional.

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

